# Form sending mail thrice in laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email, laravel-5

I have this weird issue that I have never came across before ever since I started learning laravel.

I have a contact form: **contact.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/contact-form', 'id' => 'formContact']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
        {!! Form::label('full_name', 'Full Name:', ['class' => 'fw_400']) !!}
        {!! Form::text('full_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 form-group">
        {!! Form::label('email', 'Email:', ['class' => 'fw_400']) !!}
        {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 form-group">
        {!! Form::label('contact', 'Contact Number:', ['class' => 'fw_400']) !!}
        {!! Form::text('contact', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm']) !!}
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
        {!! Form::label('contact_message', 'Contact Message:', ['class' => 'fw_400']) !!}
        {!! Form::textarea('contact_message', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'rows' => 5]) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block btnContactOnContactPage']) !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

When I click on the submit button, AJAX call is made.. Here's the ajax handler:

```
(function() {
    $('#formContact').submit(function(e) {

        $('.btnContactOnContactPage').prop('disabled', true);

        var inputData = $('#formContact').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: $('#formContact').attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: inputData,
            success: function(m) {
                $('.btnContactOnContactPage').prop('disabled', false);

                if (m.status === 'success') {
                    toastr.success(m.msg);

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        window.location.reload();
                    }, 3000)
                }
            },
            error: function(e) {
                if (e.status === 422) {

                    $('.btnContactOnContactPage').prop('disabled', false);

                    var errors = e.responseJSON;

                    var errorsHtml = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><ul>';
                    errorsHtml += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>';
                    $.each(errors, function(key, value) {
                        errorsHtml += '<li class="text-danger">' + value[0] + '</li>';
                    });
                    errorsHtml += '</ul></div>';
                    $('.errors').html(errorsHtml);
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
})();
```

And the controller method:

```
public function postContact(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'full_name'       => 'required',
        'email'           => 'required|email',
        'contact'         => 'required|regex:/^[0-9+\-]+$/',
        'contact_message' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $prevContactCode = DB::table('contact_messages')->latest()->limit(1)->pluck('cont_code');
        if ($prevContactCode == "" || empty($prevContactCode)) {
            $request['cont_code'] = 'CON-000001';
        }
        else {
            $request['cont_code'] = ++$prevContactCode;
        }

        $contactMessage = ContactMessage::create($request->all());

        $dataToMail = [
            'cont_code'       => $contactMessage->cont_code,
            'full_name'       => $contactMessage->full_name,
            'email'           => $contactMessage->email,
            'contact'         => $contactMessage->contact,
            'contact_message' => $contactMessage->contact_message
        ];

        $mail = Mail::send('emails.contact', $dataToMail, function ($message) use($dataToMail)
        {
            $message->from($dataToMail['email'], $dataToMail['full_name']);
            $message->to('contact@example.com', 'Example Contact')
                    ->subject('Contact Form Details from example.com (Form No.:' . $dataToMail['cont_code'] . ')')
                    ->cc(['ex@example.net', 'exam@hotmail.com'])
                    ->bcc(['examp@gmail.com', 'esmap@example.net']);
        });

        var_dump($mail); // displays **int 5** in chrome console

        dd($mail); // displays **5** in chrome console

        if ($mail) {
            return response(['status' => 'success', 'msg' => 'Contact form details has been successfully submitted.']);
        }
    }

    return response(['status' => 'failed', 'msg' => 'Something went wrong. Please try again later.']);
}
```

The issue is that, the **mail is sent thrice** instead of just once. I don't know what is happening here. Earlier [maybe 5 months back], it was working correctly, and now, all of a sudden, it started doing this. I am trying to figure out what is the reason behind this, but to no success. I have also updated the framework using `composer update` but the issue still exists.

**EDIT 1**: I was playing trial and error with the `Mail` facade, and I guess the issue is in `bcc` method, because I tried no `bcc` and `cc`, it worked as expected. Then again I tried with just `cc` and no `bcc`, this time also it worked correctly as expected but when added `bcc` with `cc`, I received the same mail thrice.

Where I have made the mistake ? Kindly help me out.

Comment: open your browser console and see how many requests are being sent using ajax.

Comment: Only 1 request is sent using ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some mail drivers, usually Mandrill, [sends CC'ed & BCC'ed emails as separate emails instead of treating them as a single email](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9875).

I haven't used mailtrap, but same thing might be happening in your case too.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link.

Answer (score 0):

Common cause of this issue could be that click propogation is not prevented. Which means that even if you interact with other control placed on top could possibly send the request.

Another cause is that click method binding is happening more that one time. It happens when you are binding the click event once server response comes. In such case this is a common issue.

It would be great if you could try add console.log on click events which initializes request. And see how many times it gets logged.

Still if you can't narrow it down would be great if you could extract subset of code and post it on JSfiddle or something so others can take a look.

Hope it will help.

Comment: @user3514160 I could see that you also specified earlier in comment that even Ajax request is one in network tab. It seems that then issue is further in server or in mail server. If there is way you can check code to send an email and if there is test mail server you can check your workflow against i think that might narrow it down.